# What does "Virtualization" in the Task Manager on Windows do?

Tags: windows, virtualization, task-manager

If I open up the list of running processes in the Task Manager on my Windows Vista. Then I can right-click on a process and chose "Virtualization". Not much happens after that.

What does this really do? What can I use it for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The Task Manager Virtualization column
>   corresponds to UAC file and registry
>   virtualization, a compatibility
>   feature. Please see the following
>   article for a high-level overview of
>   file and registry virtualization
>   (second bullet point in the article):
>
> http://blogs.msdn.com/uac/archive/2006/02/22/537129.aspx
>
> For some details on when
>   virtualization is enabled for a
>   process, see the following comments:
>
> http://blogs.msdn.com/uac/archive/2006/02/22/537129.aspx#549260

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/30012b5d-1331-4e85-aeb5-edaf3de17608/)